# spacemacs and org-log-done

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

In org-mode for emacs I used to get a prompt while closing a recurring task. This gave the ability to leave a note.

Trying to configure this with org-log-done hasn't worked out.

Anyone an idea how to get this functionality?

---- just to explain ---

in org-mode for emacs I can change the setting:

**M-x Customize Variable**

**org-log-done**

While using spacemacs the customisation isn't available via this route. In line 107 of the file `layers/+emacs/org/packages.el` is written: `org-log-done t`
To my idea this is a spacemacs file. Trying to change the `t` to `note` (as it would be the setting via the original method) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting something like that in user-init function will work:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (setq org-log-done 'note))
```

Edit: org-mode -> org

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction:
in **(define dotspacemacs/user-config ()**
`with-eval-after-load 'org `

` (setq org-log-done 'note)))`

Now it works.